# Flowchart About Looping

Tags: python, loops, flowchart

how to make a flowchart from this python code below

```
sum_hessian = 0.0
for idx in lhs_indices:
    sum_hessian += hessian[idx]
```

and the value of hessian and lhs_indices are below:

```
hessian = [0.5, 0.8, 1.2, 0.3, 2.0]
lhs_indices = [1, 3, 4]
```

expected process of each iteration are below:

```
(idx = 1): sum_hessian = 0.0 + 0.8 = 0.8
(idx = 3): sum_hessian = 0.8 + 0.3 = 1.1
(idx = 4): sum_hessian = 1.1 + 2.0 = 3.1
```

Thank you

I haven't found an example of a flowchart for that loop. I'm confused about how to make it, I think that is different from loop that usually used, with format for i=0, i<3, i++.

Comment: Is there a reason you want a flowchart? I rarely use them now. Be aware that there is no formal definition of a flowchart that depicts a for loop.

Comment: Do you just want an output printed to screen showing what's after your "expected process of each iteration below"?

Comment: You can replace the sum with this print statement: ```print(f"({idx = }): {sum_hessian = } + {hessian[idx]} = {(sum_hessian := sum_hessian + hessian[idx])}")```, but I don't see why you would need it this verbose.

Comment: I need a flowchart for my research assignment. I have to make a flowchart of an algorithm, and in that algorithm there is a code in the form of a loop as I asked

Comment: @MattPitkin No , I just wanna show the expected process for context of my question

Comment: Where have you found examples of flowcharts before now? I now find flowcharts needlessly confusing (and I prefer program source code), except for very rare circumstances.

Comment: @quamrana I just google it

Comment: `i=0, i<3, i++`  is start,stop,increment. The `idx in lhs_indices` expression can be thought of in the same way : start with the first, stop at the end, get the next. So just form a flowchart if required on this basis.